# Accessing the WebService in android using kSoap2

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

I have been digging since last three days to find out the appropriate way to use kSoap2 in order to access the web service. now i am able to access the web service , but i need to know, whether i followed  the right way or i have gone out of standards. I have posted complete code and output that i have got, please correct me , if i have gone wrong anywhere.

`// WebServiceConsumer.java`

```
 public SoapObject soap(String METHOD_NAME, String SOAP_ACTION, String NAMESPACE, String URL) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {

    /** Construction of the SoapObject */
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); //set up request
    /** passing the values in to the webservice*/
    request.addProperty("iTopN", "0"); //variable name, value. got the variable name, from the wsdl file!

    /** Creation of the SoapEnvelope with the appropriate version*/
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); //put all required data into a soap envelope
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);  //prepare request
    /** Creating AndroidTransport for passing the request to the URL where the service is located*/
    AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);  
    httpTransport.debug = true;  //this is optional, use it if you don't want to use a packet sniffer to check what the sent message was (httpTransport.requestDump)
    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); //send request
    SoapObject result =(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn; //get response
    return result;
 }

 public void callService() {
     try{
         SoapObject result = soap(METHOD_NAME, SOAP_ACTION, NAMESPACE, URL);
         Log.i(TAG,"Result:" + result);
         try {
            // FootballScoreParser.parseBusinessObject(result.getProperty(0).toString(), footballscore);
                 SoapObject logObject = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(0);
                 Log.i(TAG,"LogObject : " + logObject);
                 for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
                 SoapObject logger = (SoapObject) logObject.getProperty(i);
                // Log.i(TAG,"Name : " + logger.getProperty("sName"));
                // Log.i(TAG,"Goals : "+ logger.getProperty("iGoals"));

                 /** Appending the sName,iGoals in to ArrayList name */
                    name.add((String)logger.getProperty("sName").toString());
                    goals.add((String) logger.getProperty("iGoals").toString());
                    country.add((String) logger.getProperty("sCountry").toString());
                    flag.add((String) logger.getProperty("sFlag").toString());

                 /** Converting the ArrayList into the Object Array*/
                    objName = name.toArray();
                    objGoals = goals.toArray();
                    objCountry = country.toArray();
                    objFlags = flag.toArray();
                 }
                 for(int j = 0; j < objName.length; j++){
                            Log.i(TAG,"Name ["+ j + "]=" + objName[j].toString() + "," + "Goals ["+ j + "]=" + objGoals[j].toString()+ ","  + "Country[" + j  + "]=" + objCountry[j].toString() + "," +"Flag[" +j+ "]=" + objFlags[j].toString());

                         }
                 }
         catch(Exception err){
             Log.i(TAG, "" + err);
         }


         }
         catch(Exception err){
             Log.i(TAG,""+ err);
         }
           /* catch(NumberFormatException err){
            err.printStackTrace();  
            }
            catch(IllegalArgumentException err){
                err.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(IllegalAccessException err){
                err.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(InstantiationException err){
                err.printStackTrace();
            }*/
         //}
```

`// FootBallScrorerActivity.java`

```
package com.project.mobile.FootballScorers;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class FootbalScorerActivity extends Activity {
WebServiceConsumer webconsumer;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    webconsumer = new WebServiceConsumer();
    webconsumer.callService();

}
}
```

Output:

[Please click here to see the Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozJbm.png)

Any Help is Appreciated.... Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the output, it looks to me like your web service returns LogObject, which means it is a complex object. To work with complex objects, you should implement the same class in Android as well, and implement the KSOAP Marshal interface. After that you should register Add mapping to that class so that KSOAP knows how to handle the received object.

For more information on how to work with complex objects with KSOAP on Android, follow this tutorial:

[KSOAP Android Web Service Tutorial with Sample Code on Complex Objects](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html)

Comment: Ya, This approach  helped me a lot. Thanks Glad to Help... i will post my code once its over. Thanks a lot